Can this integral equation be solved?
I am trying to find out the Stationary Distribution of a Continuous State Space Markov Chain.
For example, consider a Gaussian Transition Kernel that describes the probability of moving from point $x$ to $x'$:
$$T(x, x') \sim N(x, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
I am interested in determining what is the Stationary Distribution for this process.
I know that to determine the Stationary Distribution for this problem, we have to find a distribution $\pi(x)$ such that the following relationship holds (Detailed Balance Condition, also called the Reversibility Condition):
$$\int T(x, x')\pi(x)dx = \pi(x'), \quad \forall x'$$
Is it possible to solve the above equation for $\pi(x)$?
I know that in the context of Discrete Time and Discrete State Space Markov Chains, we can find the Stationary Distribution $\pi$ by solving the following equation:
$$\pi = P \cdot \pi$$
However, I am not sure how to solve the equivalent equation for the Continuous State Space version.
Here is what I tried so far.
1) Intuition
When dealing with functions of the Gaussian Distribution, properties of the Gaussian Functions tend to also be Gaussian. This makes me believe that if the Stationary Distribution exists, it also Gaussian.
I know that the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean (Proof that the gaussian distribution is "symmetric".), i.e. $f(x) = f(-x)$. This means:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}} = f(-x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(-x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
I thought of the following way to show this:
If the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean point $\mu$, this means that any two points $x_1$ and $x_2$ that are equidistant from $\mu$ will have the following properties:
$$x_1 - \mu = \mu - x_2$$
$$\mu = \frac{x_1 +x_2}{2}$$
$$f(x_1) = f(x_2)$$
$$f(\mu + \Delta) = f(\mu - \Delta)$$
Symmetry using this condition implies that:
$$ \exp\left[ - \frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1 - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_2 - \mu}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] $$
Looking at the LHS, we see:
$$ \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_1 - \frac{{x_1 + x_2}}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] =  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{2x_1 - (x_1 + x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{x_1 - x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{ 
 {x_1 - x_2)}}   {2\cdot\sigma}\right)^2\right]$$
Now, the same is true for the RHS:
$$ \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{x_2 - \frac{{x_1 + x_2}}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] =  \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{2x_2 - (x_1 + x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{x_1 - x_2)}{2}}{\sigma}\right)^2\right] = \exp\left[-\frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{ 
 {x_1 - x_2)}}   {2\cdot\sigma}\right)^2\right]$$
Thus, we can see that LHS = RHS and that the Gaussian Distribution is symmetric around the mean.
Going back to the Detailed Balance Condition, we can see that:
$$\pi(x)T(x, x') = \pi(x')T(x', x)$$
Thus, if we assume that $\pi(x)$ is a Gaussian, we can write:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-x')^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
Using the fact that the Gaussian distribution is symmetric, i.e $e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} = e^{-\frac{(x-x')^2}{2\sigma^2}}$, we can write:
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}}$$
Thus, based on the assumption that $\pi(x)$ is Gaussian, we can show that $\pi(x)$ satisfies the Detailed Balance Condition and is a Stationary Distribution:
$$\int T(x, x')\pi(x)dx = \pi(x'), \quad \forall x'$$
Substituting the Gaussian transition kernel $T(x, x')$ and assume $\pi(x)$ is a Gaussian distribution, we get:
$$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}} \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} dx = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}}, \quad \forall x'$$
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\mu^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-\mu)^2}{2\mu^2}}, \quad \forall x'$$
But this still has not been proved in my opinion.
2) Computer Simulation
I tried to write a computer simulation in R (Programming Language) that simulates random draws from this Transition Kernel and then uses the Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic to compare the EDF (empirical distribution function) to the theoretical CDF (cumulative distribution function) of a Normal Distribution. In my opinion, this might be able to show that the Stationary Distribution of this Transition Kernel is Gaussian.
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

 #parameters of the Gaussian transition kernel
mu <- 0
sigma <- 1

# total number of simulations (n) and burn-in observations (m)
n <- 1000
m <- 100  


chain <- numeric(n)


chain[1] <- rnorm(1, mean = mu, sd = sigma)

#arkov chain
for (i in 2:n) {
    chain[i] <- rnorm(1, mean = chain[i - 1], sd = sigma)
}


df <- data.frame(Value = chain, Time = 1:n)

# indicator variable for before/after burn-in
df$Period <- ifelse(df$Time <= m, "Before Burn-in", "After Burn-in")
df1 = df[df$Period == "After Burn-in",]

# trajectory of the Markov chain 
p1 <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Time, y = Value)) +
    geom_line(aes(color = Period)) +
    geom_vline(xintercept = m, linetype = "dashed", color = "gray") +  # Add burn-in line
    labs(
        title = paste("Trajectory of the Markov Chain (", n, " simulations)", sep = ""),
        subtitle = paste("Estimated Mean (μ) after Burn-in:", round(mean(chain_burned), 3),
                         "\nEstimated SD (σ) after Burn-in:", round(sd(chain_burned), 3)),
        x = "Time",
        y = "State"
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Before Burn-in" = "blue", "After Burn-in" = "red"))

# histogram
p2 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Value)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density.., fill = "Histogram"), bins = 50, alpha = 0.5) +
    stat_function(
        fun = dnorm,
        args = list(mean = mean(chain_burned), sd = sd(chain_burned)),
        aes(color = "Gaussian Density"),
        size = 1
    ) +
    labs(
        title = paste("Estimated Stationary Distribution (", n, " simulations)", sep = ""),
        subtitle = paste("Estimated Mean (μ) after Burn-in:", round(mean(chain_burned), 3),
                         "\nEstimated SD (σ) after Burn-in:", round(sd(chain_burned), 3)),
        x = "State",
        y = "Density"
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_fill_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Histogram" = "skyblue")) +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("Gaussian Density" = "red"))

#Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic
ks_result <- ks.test(chain_burned, "pnorm", mean = mean(chain_burned), sd = sd(chain_burned))

# EDF vs. CDF plot

p3 <- ggplot(df1, aes(x = Value)) +
    stat_ecdf(aes(color = "EDF")) +
    stat_function(
        fun = pnorm,
        args = list(mean = mean(chain_burned), sd = sd(chain_burned)),
        aes(color = "CDF"),
        linetype = "dashed",
        size = 1
    ) +
    labs(
        title = paste(
            "EDF of Observed Data vs. CDF of Normal Distribution (",
            n,
            " simulations, KS Statistic:",
            round(ks_result$statistic, 3),
            ", p-value:",
            format(ks_result$p.value, digits = 3),
            ")",
            sep = ""
        ),
        subtitle = if (ks_result$p.value > 0.05) "Conclusion: EDF is the same as CDF" else "Conclusion: EDF is different from CDF",
        x = "State",
        y = "Cumulative Probability"
    ) +
    theme_minimal() +
    scale_color_manual(name = "Legend", values = c("EDF" = "blue", "CDF" = "red"))


grid.arrange(p1, p2, p3, ncol=1)


However, I am not still not sure if this counts as a proof
In general, if we start with a Gaussian Transition Kernel, is it possible to derive the Stationary Distribution from first principles, i.e solve the following integral equation?
$$T(x, x') \sim N(x, \sigma^2) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma^2}}e^{-\frac{(x'-x)^2}{2\sigma^2}}$$
$$\int T(x, x')\pi(x)dx = \pi(x'), \quad \forall x'$$
$$\pi(x) \sim ???$$
Or unlike the Discrete State Space version, solving this equation for $\pi$ in the continuous state space version is simply not possible?
Thanks!

TL;DR No, there is no probabilistic distribution satisfying these conditions because a uniform distribution on all real numbers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ does not exist.
The problem you are facing is that the state space is unlimited and the distribution is symetric with respect to translation, so the state of the Markov chain may exceed any bound with non-zero probability. The Gaussian distribution can do this even by a single step. But even if you had a bounded distribution, you could still jump by multiple steps arbitrarily far away using non-zero probability. That way, the stationary distribution must have a non-zero distribution at every point. Also given that the transition distribution is translationally symmetric, the stationary distribution must be also translationally symmetric, therefore it has to be uniform. And there is no uniform distribution on all real numbers.
You could help the situation in two ways:

Limiting the station space. You can cut off the states which are father than a limit. And if it happens that the state ends past the limit, you just re-roll the state until you get something within the limit. In terms of mathematics, you cut the transition distribution past the limit and re-normalise it. You can also wrap the state space around, so the states move in a circle.
You alter the transition distribution to break the translational symmetry. Reducing the standard deviation for points farther away from the origin may work.

Now the question is, what your simulation actually does. It may seem to you that the distribution actually converges somewhere but it is only an illusion. It moves slower and slower but it does not converge to any probabilistic distribution. In the first step, you get a normal distribution with $\sigma=1$. After the second step, you add an independent normal distribution with $\sigma=1$. Independent distributions sum in a way so the $\sigma^2$ sum up, so you get a normal distribution with $\sigma^2=2$, therefore $\sigma=\sqrt2$. After $10^6$ steps, you get $\sigma^2=10^6$, therefore you get a normal distribution with $\sigma=1000$, which corresponds pretty well with your plot. So after $n$ steps, you get a normal distribution with $\sigma=\sqrt{n}$ and this simply does not converge.

@ Hume2: thank you so much for your reply. You mention that a Uniform Distribution does not exist on the reals. When I look at the wikipedia page (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuous_uniform_distribution), the Uniform Distribution is defined between two constants "a" and "b" ... and it seems like it can take any value between them?

I meant that there is no uniform distribution on all real numbers from $-\infty$ to $\infty$. Of course that you can have a uniform distribution between two given finite bounds.

Thats a very interesting point you raise towards the end about summing gaussians and the impact that has on their variances. I had never thought about that. thank you

I tried to show that if $\pi(x)$ is a Gaussian Distribution, the Detailed Balance Condition  (DBC) is satisfied. Is my argument wrong? It seems like if $\pi(x)$ is Gaussian, then the DBC is met?

Can you please explain this comment a bit more, "No, there is no probabilistic distribution satisfying these conditions because a uniform distribution on all real numbers from −∞ to ∞ does not exist.". I started with the idea that perhaps $\pi(x)$ is Gaussian. Where does the Uniform Distribution come into play then?

So if I choose T(x,x') as a Gaussian Transition Kernel, there is no stationary distribution? In Metropolis Hastings (MH) algorithm, I heard that it is often acceptable to use a Gaussian Distribution as a proposal distribution (i.e. candidate distribution). Using the correct accept-reject rule, we can use the Gaussian Distribution (the mean of this Gaussian is constantly being updated to the last accepted point) to sample from the Target Distribution. MH works on the fact that the stationary distribution of the proposal converges to the target distribution.

I am a bit confused now. If the Gaussian Transition Kernel does not have a stationary distribution, how can it be used in the Metropolis Hastings algorithm then?

Thank you so much for all your help! :)

Well, MH algorithm uses also other rules for the transitions, Gaussian distribution is only one step in the algorithm. If you express the MH algorithm as a Markov chain, you get a different transition distributions and therefore it may actually converge.
